# Choosing the mode of a string by group in SAS

Tags: sas

It seems like a very simple operation, but I cannot find an easy way of doing it. I have a dataset with clients ID and days of the week for every purchase. I just want to have the modal value of `weekday` by `id`

```
DATA have;
 INPUT id weekday $;
CARDS;
1 Thursday
1 Monday
1 Monday
2 Tuesday
2 Thursday
2 Tuesday
;
RUN; 

DATA want;
 INPUT id weekday $;
CARDS;
1 Monday
2 Tuesday
;
RUN;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, one way could be to:

1. First count the number of weekdays by both id and weekdays itself;
2. Then get only the max() of the count variable by id.

Of course, if you have a multimodal group, this will get you as many rows by id as the number of modes it has:

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select distinct
*
from (select
    *,
    count(weekday) as N
    from have
    group by id, weekday)
group by id
having N=max(N);
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Proc FREQ` to count the number of items in `BY` group partitions and a `DATA` Step to filter out the `mode` values.

Example:

```
proc freq data=have noprint order=freq;
  by id;
  table weekday / out=counts;
run;

data want;
  set counts;
  by id;

  * output multiple rows if there is a frequency count tie;

  if first.id then _mode_count = count;
  if _mode_count = count;

  retain _mode_count;
  keep id weekday;
run;
```

Comment: It worked, thanks! Let me see: The sequence: In the proc freq, you order by freq, which you also called count. Then in the data step  you create a new variable that was called mode that gets a value (count) only if it is the first row by id. Then you retain only when mode=count, deleting the other rows. Is that right?

Comment: `order=freq` tells the procedure to output the tabled variable values and counts in descending count order (highest frequency first, thus the mode is first). `out=counts` names the output data set.  The output data contains columns (aka variable) for the `by` group, the `table`d variable and the within group computations frequency count in `count` and percent in `percent`.  The worker variable maintains the count from the first row in the group, which is the mode by design of the freq options and statement coded. if _mode=count;` is a subsetting if, that, yes in effect, deletes the other rows.

Comment: Also, FYI, `Proc UNIVARIATE` which also computes mode (for numeric variables only) chooses the lowest value as the mode when there are ties in the frequency count.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the detailed clarifications!